# How is capital gains from sale of listed bonds taxed in India?

Tags: income-tax, india, capital-gains-tax

Bonds in question:
INE092T08CD4 IDFC FIRST BANK LIMITED TRANCHE-1 SR-II NCD 12NV20 FVRS5000

An Indian resident purchased these bonds in fy2010 and sold them in fy2019 - a year before maturity - and thereby incurs long term capital gains. As per my understanding, no indexation (of purchase price) is allowed in this case. At what rate are the gains taxable?

Schedule CG of the ITR2 excel utility seems to have two different sections to report this:

B2. From sale of bonds or debenture (other than capital indexed bonds issued by Government)

B3. From sale of, (i) listed securities (other than a unit) or zero coupon bonds where proviso under section 112(1) is applicable

B2 seems to be taxable at 20% without indexation and B3 at 10% without indexation.

Which one is applicable in the above case?

Comment: This seems to be under 80ccf where interest taxable as ordinary income.  Have you actually made gains

Comment: @Dheer thanks for your response. Yes I made gains when I sold them in the market. My broker's capital gains statement classifies the trade under the cryptic heading of: "Long Term Capital Gain (STT not paid and booked profit is less than double of Index Profit)". Per my understanding, it is only treated as interest if you let it mature right? These bonds were under cumulative interest option.

Comment: B2 seems logical,  better to get a professional advice from CA if the amount is significant.

Comment: @Dheer Thanks. Could you please share why you think B2 seems more appropriate than B3? It is a listed security right? Although I don't know what they mean by "other than a unit"

Comment: I was searching for the same question and landed here.  What did you finally decide to do?

Comment: @vivekv I went ahead with b3 after discussing with my CA

Answer (score 3):

"Long Term Capital Gain (STT not paid and booked profit is less than double of Index Profit)" sounds cryptic but actually it helps you decide between B2 and B3.Let me explain. You can either pay 10% of booked profit (selling proceed - cost of acquisition) or pay 20% of index profit (selling proceed - cost of acquisition with indexation). Let us say both of these are b & i respectively.

So your choices are 0.1*b or 0.2*i for tax. Obviously, we want to pay minimum tax. So you would want to choose booked profit (and not take indexation benefit) if 0.1*b < 0.2*i
which implies b < 2*i

which is another way of saying booked profit is less than double of index profit. :)
So you should choose B3 in this case.

P.S.: I know you already filed details long back but posting it in case someone else stumbles on this query like I did looking for an answer earlier. :)